# AWS Lambda: no items in Destination list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I created a Lambda function which takes data from one SQS queue, perform some modifications and should put the output data to another SQS queue. But trying to specify the Destination, I'm getting the empty list of SQS queues:

[image]

**Could you please help me?**

Permissions for Lambda function are provided:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:TagQueue",
                "sqs:UntagQueue",
                "sqs:PurgeQueue"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:myaccountid:my-queue.fifo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried two configurations of Access Policy for SQS queue. With VPC:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:myacy-queuecountid:m.fifo",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceVpc": "my-vpc"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and Principal Account:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:myaccountid:my-queue.fifo",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalAccount": [
            "myaccountid"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

(*myaccountid*, *myqueue*, *my-vpc* are the masks for valid values)

But result is the same - list of available SQS queues is empty

Comment: So you have a queue that triggers the lambda and another queue that take the processed data from the lamda? Dose the second queue exist/is it already created? Have you tried to provide sqs:* to see if it helps? Maybe you need the possibility to list them?

Comment: Yes, that's right - first queue is a Trigger, second one should be a Destination. Yes, second queue exists.  
I just checked changing Lambda Role Policy using "sqs:*", but, unfortunately, the issue is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Destinations` are only for [asynchronous invocations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) of lambda. SQS invokes lambda [synchronously](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html), thus `Destinations` do not apply. This is not the cause why it does not show up in your list, but you would never be able to use in the first place due to `Destinations` with SQS invoking lambda.

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Asynchronous invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html)

> You can also configure Lambda to send an *invocation record* to another service. Lambda supports the following destinations for asynchronous invocation.
>
> - Amazon SQS – A ***standard*** SQS queue.
> - Amazon SNS – An SNS topic.
> - AWS Lambda – A Lambda function.
> - Amazon EventBridge – An EventBridge event bus.
>
> *The invocation record contains details about the request and response in JSON forma*.

The SQS queue must be *standard*, your queue is *fifo*.

You can send a message to a fifo queue using an SDK.